# Threads in Android Services, is this a good idea?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service

I want to know if is this a good idea to start a `thread` inside an Android `Service`?

or the best practice is to use the service body and do your stuffs there?

Comment: First question:No Second question: Yes

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a good practice and you should do it when this Service has to do some work for indefinite time. If you want to do some single action, use IntentService instead. 
Service can also be bound to any other component (Activity, another Service) and be started at the same time, so you can do work in background even when app is minimized or closed.
Imagine, you have to do some long running operations for indefinite time and interact by UI with those operations. To do that create service, start it and bind to it at the same time. You'll get interface for controlling this service from ServiceConnection during binding. Service can do long running operation in meantime. The point here, that different Activitis can bind to this service and represent operation in different way.
Intent service, on the other hand, running its own background thread by default, but, it stops authomatically when work on that thread is complete.

Comment: I would add the information that `Service` runs on the thread you start it. So you might create a Thread just to start `Service`, and it runs on separate Thread than `main`.